# React - embed props into iframe url

Tags: api, reactjs, iframe, maps, embed

I'm new to react and trying to embed the longitude and latitude from an api into a google maps iframe

```
<br />  
<iframe name="gMap" src ="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={ this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat },{ this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng }&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
<br />
```

The lng,lat coords render to the page under the iframe fine

```
Lat: { (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat : '' }
<br />
Lng: { (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng : '' }
```

I figure this is probably easy to do but can't seem to embed them in the url. TIA

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please try to be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to display a google map location on the page based on data I'm getting from an api. The data renders fine except when I try to embed it in the google map url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Just update your code like this:

```
<br/>  
    <iframe name="gMap" 
      src={`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat},
        ${this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng}&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed`}></iframe>
<br/>
```

### Update

We have two options:

#### React Google Maps

This is a React Component for integration of Google Maps. It is quite simple and efficient. Check that from [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps).

#### Goole Maps Embed Api

To solve `sameorigin` issue, We can use [Embed Api for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide). All you have to do is to generate an `API_KEY`. Then:

```
const API_KEY = "Your_API_KEY_Here"

class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <iframe name="gMap" src={`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=${this.props.location.lat},${ this.props.location.lng}&key=${API_KEY}`}></iframe>
    )
  }
}
```

I created a pen to show an example. Just set your API KEY to `API_KEY` const. Here its [link](https://codepen.io/aoguzhan/pen/RLRwpe?editors=1010#0). It is working You can play with it.

**Note:** You must create an API KEY for Google Maps Embed Service

Comment: Tnx. I used that but it seemed to lose the location - Search.js:110 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null

Comment: That means `this.props.venue.selectedVenue` is `null`. Debug your code to check the value of `this.props.venue.selectedVenue` in your `render` method. Because this code is syntactically correct. @Stev

Comment: Tnx Alix. Not sure why it wouldn't display there but would outside the iframe. I modified it to cancel out if no lat,lng data was available

src={`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${ (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat : '' }...

It did embed the coords but appended multiple + after.

Error msg - Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/maps?q=40.74364025488197,++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-73.9928880036041&hl=es;z%3D14&amp;output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Hardcode the lng,lat and map shows up fine

Comment: @Stev see my updated answer and codepen example in it.

Comment: Tnx heaps Alix, appreciate the help - After getting various errors adding the const I ended up getting it working by using <iframe name="gMap" src={`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=${ (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat : '' },${ (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng : '' }&key=xxxx-my-api-key-xxxxx`}></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

You want to use backquotes here:

`src ="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={ this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat },{ this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng }&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed"` becomes:

`` src=`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${ this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat },${ this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng }&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed` `` (also, there is no space between `src` and `=`)

Comment: Tnx heaps. Code looked better in Atom immediately but got the error Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (109:73) This (109:73) happens on the equals sign after src.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up solving the problem. Tnx to Alix & DrunkDevKek for getting me on the right path

```
<br />
<iframe name="gMap" src={`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=${ (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lat : '' },${ (this.props.venue.selectedVenue) ? this.props.venue.selectedVenue.location.lng : '' }&key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY`}></iframe>
<br />
```